Will i be held responsible/accountable for the unintentional unwanted touches that occur during a public transport
I am a person studying general, and for coaching, I need to travel a certain way by bus every day. As a high density of population in Dhaka,  people get into the bus like goods are tied in sacks, because it is seen that despite my best efforts, the bodies of various women are thrown when the bus brakes or speeds up.
Now, will I accept responsibility for this?
I don't do it willingly at all. Even today I was hanging hard to save me; even my hand was impacted, and when the bus braked, the girl behind me fell on me. I know it was not her fault, and besides, women are mentally stronger than men. I may fall under the deception of the devil; I may not today, but if it is almost like that, if I fall one day, is there any deed to save me from it?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I've edited your question you don't address a shaykh here, but people that are interested in Islam and its teachings.

Assalamu'alykum akhi hope you are doing well and we will advise you that first of all you have to step back from that bus because it is leading you towards zina and just like propeht SAW said "The shayateen runs in the body of son of Adam just like the blood runs in the nerves"  (Sahih Muslim) and another option you have which can help you to prevent this is that IT IS YOUR RESPONSIBILITY AND NECESSARY NEED AKHI Try to understand IT IS YOUR responsibility to go early to catch the seat or at least at least to get a area of standing in the bus where men or any location at least surrounds it, but if you are not or will be not able to take this responsibility of this then for surely it will be 1/1 winning better for you to leave this bus and select something else like taxi part by part or bicycle(if the destination is not much away) or a bike or scooter if it suits your pocket or do anything instead of keeping with where are you currently and the reason is because you know that "by mistake or incidently once or twice, there is no problem in that but if it will be on regular basis it can 100% lead you because you are a man and it's natural that's why Yusuf Alayhis Salaam ran away from that room rather than staying up there and saying that I have taqwa and it is my emergency or a test but no, he ran away and create a inspiration for us and just like Allah said in SUrah aAL Isra verse 32 that "Do not even go near to adultery" so these evidence literally shows upon your situation that you have to ran away from it just like Allah Commanded and one of his Prophet did instead of being a spunchbob so if you know that and definitely every male person know that out there and if you are still not stepping back from this even if you know that then you are sinful for it for sure and Allah will not be please with you no matter what worldly matters or exceptions you have so hope it helps you up and May Allah make it easy for you to make it easy for you to take your responsibility easily. End quote. Allah knows best.
